# Timeout when starting Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat8

My server.xml is configured to use Apache in connection to Tomcat. If I start Tomcat with startup.sh,  it works fine because I can access a simple html-file located in webapps/ROOT at port 80 and 443.
Netstat -tulpn shows that a java process occupies the 8005 and 8009 ports.
Then I run shutdown.sh, and the netstat shows the ports are no longer occupied.
I try to start Tomcat from Eclipse. The console says it is started within 10000ms. The ports 8005 and 8009 are occupied by a javaprocess, but in Eclipse I get timeout, and the state of the server is 'Starting'.
I try to start a html-script that calls the restful web service, but I get 503 Service unavailable. I've stuggled with this the whole day. I do not understand what to do with this. Please help !

Comment: Check for any java process that is running, kill them and try restarting.

Comment: I have just solved this problem. It was due to my java version 8 was not supported by Tomcat version 8.5. I had to install tomcat version 9. Them I got another problem when I added tomcat to Eclipse. That was Unknown version of Tomcat. I eventually solved that problem too by setting my user as the owner of the apache-tomcat-directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem. It was due to my java version 8 was not supported by Tomcat version 8.5. I had to install tomcat version 9. Then I got another problem when I added tomcat to Eclipse. That was Unknown version of Tomcat. I eventually solved that problem too by setting my user as the owner of the apache-tomcat-directory.